# Is there any URDF plugin available for Autodesk Fusion 360?

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey There,

I am currently using Solidworks to model a Robotic Arm, and "SW2URDF" plugin to generate the URDF file( so that I can  run that in Gazebo and Rviz).

But I wish to switch to Autodesk Fusion 360. Is there any URDF plugin available for Autodesk Fusion 360?.

Thank You.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237137/is-there-any-urdf-plugin-available-for-autodesk-fusion-360?/) by [Ashwin Balaram B](https://answers.ros.org/users/27188/ashwin-balaram-b/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I wrote a Fusion 360 script to export URDF.

https://github.com/syuntoku14/fusion2urdf

Currently, this can export only revolute joint. Let me know if your model contains joints except for revolute.

I hope this will help you!

---

Originally posted by [syuntoku14](https://answers.ros.org/users/36455/syuntoku14/) with karma: 36 on 2018-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Phenomenal](https://answers.ros.org/users/57360/phenomenal/) on 2020-08-05**:
My model has some slider joints! I want to convert it to urdf, so that I can use it in ros-gazebo